# Sybase change outer joins (*= or =*) to ANSI joins

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase, ansi-c

After migration from Mysql to Sybase database I have to rewrite some of the codes. Unfortunately, I cannot find the correct way to do it, I give a short example of one of the codes, It was automatically written by Business Object Universe designer. Mainly I would like to understand how to change these right =* or left *= joins correctly so I could change other codes by myself. The reason is that Sybase doesn't allow to use both ANSI and Transact-SQL in a single selection.

Tried to change it just to outer joins, but the results are incorrect it provides too much data.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  Y15YVF_FLEET_P.FLEET_NUM,
  AVG(Y15YVF_INVOICE.REVAL),
  Y15YVF_FLEET_P.LCTYP,
  Y15YVF_FLEET_P.DIVISION
FROM
  Y15YVF_CONTRACT INNER JOIN Y15YVF_FLEET_A ON (Y15YVF_FLEET_A.MANDT=*Y15YVF_CONTRACT.MANDT and Y15YVF_FLEET_A.FLEET_NUM=*Y15YVF_CONTRACT.FLEET_NUM and Y15YVF_FLEET_A.CTNR=*Y15YVF_CONTRACT.CTNR)
   INNER JOIN Y15YVF_VEHICLES ON (Y15YVF_VEHICLES.FLEET_NUM=Y15YVF_FLEET_A.FLEET_NUM and Y15YVF_VEHICLES.MANDT=Y15YVF_FLEET_A.MANDT)
   INNER JOIN Y15YVF_FLEET_P ON (Y15YVF_VEHICLES.FLEET_NUM=Y15YVF_FLEET_P.FLEET_NUM and Y15YVF_VEHICLES.MANDT=Y15YVF_FLEET_P.MANDT)
   INNER JOIN Y15YVF_INVOICE ON (Y15YVF_FLEET_A.MANDT=*Y15YVF_INVOICE.MANDT and Y15YVF_FLEET_A.FLEET_NUM=*Y15YVF_INVOICE.FLEET_NUM)

WHERE
  ( 
  Y15YVF_INVOICE.REDAT  >=  '20040601'
  AND  Y15YVF_VEHICLES.MANDT  !=  @variable('Stichtag:')
  AND  Y15YVF_FLEET_A.OWNSH  =  'L'
  AND  Y15YVF_CONTRACT.LEABEG  !=  '00000000'
  )
GROUP BY
  Y15YVF_FLEET_P.FLEET_NUM, 
  Y15YVF_FLEET_P.LCTYP, 
  Y15YVF_FLEET_P.DIVISION
```

I also add link to the sample data, as there is too much data not sure if it will be enought for checking:
[Data](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/81ed29fc22075d93c54981edbd53a5a320190619073052/b70050)

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you want:

```
FROM e JOIN
     d
     ON e.FLEET_NUM = d.FLEET_NUM AND
        e.MANDT = d.MANDT LEFT JOIN
     a
     ON e.FLEET_NUM = a.FLEET_NUM AND
        e.MANDT = a.MANDT
     b
     ON d.MANDT = b.MANDT AND d.FLEET_NUM = b.FLEET_NUM
     c 
     ON d.MANDT = c.MANDT AND d.FLEET_NUM = c.FLEET_NUM AND
        d.CTNR = c.CTNR
```

It would be easier to tell with table names and sample data.

Comment: Hello Gordon, thanks for your help, but with this code I get error: "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ON'.

Comment: I also changed code and added data sample if it helps.